# What are the names of type(myVar) and (type)myVar? Are they both bad practice?

Tags: c++, c++11, casting

Almost a rehash of [What's the difference between function(myVar) and (function)myVar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484371/whats-the-difference-between-functionmyvar-and-functionmyvar)

But I want to know:

What is the name of these variants and are they 'bad'?

`type(myVar)` is constructor like syntax, but for a basic type is it the same as doing a C-style cast which is considered bad in C++?

`(type)myVar` this one certainly does seem to be a C-style cast and thus must be bad practice?

I've seen some instances where people replace things like `(int)a` with `int(a)` citing that the C-style version is bad/wrong yet the linked question says they're both the same!

Comment: What do you mean by `function`? `int` isn't a function. Also, what are you asking for the name of? The returned object? The syntax?

Comment: The syntax, I guess function should really be type, I'll update the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the name of these variants

- `type(expr)` is known as a function-style cast.
- `(type)(expr)` is known as a C-style cast.

> and are they 'bad'?

[Yes.](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointer-casts.html) First off, both are semantically completely equivalent. They are “bad” because they aren’t safe – they might be equivalent to a `static_cast`, but equally a `reinterpret_cast`, and without knowing both `type` *and* the type of `expr` it’s impossible to say<sup>1</sup>. They also disregard access specifiers in some cases (C-style casts allow casting inside a private inheritance hierarchy). Furthermore, they are not as verbose as the explicit C++ style casts, which is a bad thing since casts are usually *meant* to stand out in C++.

---

<sup>1</sup> Consider `int(x)`: Depending on `x`’ type, this is either a `static_cast` (e.g. `auto x = 4.2f;`) or a `reinterpret_cast` (e.g. `auto x = nullptr;` on an architecture where `int` is large enough to hold a pointer).

Comment: Does this mean function-style cast is a C feature?

Comment: Do you say that doing for a `unsigned char c;`  `int(c)` would resemble the same effects as of a `reinterpret_cast<int>(c)`?

Comment: @paulm No, definitely not c.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No. I’m saying that for an (unknown) type `T`, the syntatically same cast might be either a `static_cast` or a `reinterpret_cast`. Making the cast explicit clarifies this. People are divided about whether they deem `int(c)` etc. acceptable. Personally, I don’t. If you want to use constructor-like syntax, use `int{c}` (but this only works where an implicit conversion is allowed) or `static_cast<int>(c)`, and avoid casting wherever possible. Where casts are too verbose, I wrap them in a function.

Comment: This answers my comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474933/what-exactly-is-or-was-the-purpose-of-c-function-style-casts how do you know if it would become a static or a reinterpret cast though?

Comment: @paulm In general, only by knowing all involved types and by knowing which casts are legal on these types. Consult the standard for the rules dictating between which types a `static_cast` and a `reinterpret_cast` is defined. The rules are unfortunately far from straightforward. All the more reason to avoid unclear casts which muddy the waters further.

Comment: It can also be a const_cast, might be worth mentioning.

Comment: My takeaway from this is never use it unless you have to (in templates)

Comment: @paulm Actually, you don’t have to use it even in templates (at least I haven’t come across a legitimate usage yet).