# Function style casting vs calling constructor

Tags: c++, casting

If I have a class `A`, and I write `A(5);`, it clearly makes a temporary variable.

But what is not clear if `A(5);` is a constructor call (using `5` as parameter), or if this is a function style cast, casting `5` to `A`. Can someone explain it to me please?

Comment: I do not understand, what is not clear for you. Casting an `int` to object `t` would look like `(t) 5;`.

Comment: Explain what you mean by *functional style cast*?

Comment: As the famous russian saying, goes, 'smack in the forehead is the same as the smack to the forehead'.

Comment: @RSahu http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474933/what-exactly-is-or-was-the-purpose-of-c-function-style-casts

Comment: Functional cast is also t(5)

Comment: @RSahu: yes I have already read that answer

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484371/whats-the-difference-between-functionmyvar-and-functionmyvar) will make it more clear.

Comment: I don't think the marked question is a duplicate: this is about function-style conversions vs. explicit constructor calls. Cast-notation isn't in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a functional-style type conversion which creates a `t` from an `int` by calling the constructor. There is no way to explicitly call a constructor in C++.

This is described in `[expr.type.conv]` (N3337):

> **5.2.3 Explicit type conversion (functional notation)**
>
> 1) A simple-type-specifer (7.1.6.2) or typename-specifer (14.6) followed by a parenthesized expression-list
>   constructs a value of the specified type given the expression list. If the expression list is a single expression,
>   the type conversion expression is equivalent (in definedness, and if defined in meaning) to the corresponding
>   cast expression (5.4). If the type specified is a class type, the class type shall be complete. If the expression
>   list specifies more than a single value, the type shall be a class with a suitably declared constructor (8.5, 12.1),
>   and the expression `T(x1, x2, ...)` is equivalent in effect to the declaration `T t(x1, x2, ...);` for some invented temporary variable `t`, with the result being the value of `t` as a prvalue.

Since `t` is a *simple-type-specifier*, this is equivalent to the corresponding cast expression. This is allowed to carry out the equivalent of a `static_cast` (`[expr.cast]/4`), which defines the final result of the conversion:

> `[expr.static.cast]/4:` Otherwise, an expression `e` can be explicitly converted to a type `T` using a `static_cast` of the form `static_cast<T>(e)` if the declaration `T t(e);` is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable `t` (8.5). The
>   effect of such an explicit conversion is the same as performing the declaration and initialization and then
>   using the temporary variable as the result of the conversion. The expression `e` is used as a glvalue if and
>   only if the initialization uses it as a glvalue.

Comment: Please yes if it is possible